# Cannot install Android documentation with SDK Manager

Tags: android

I've downloaded and installed android-sdk_r15-macosx, downloaded the platforms I need with the SDK Manager, but I couldn't find a way to install the docs.

Before the docs used to be in `$ANDROID_SDK/docs/`, and there was a corresponding item in the list of downloadable packages in the SDK Manager, but now I don't even see it in the list

[image: Screenshot]

`~/local$ ls android-sdk-macosx/`

`SDK Readme.txt add-ons        platform-tools platforms      samples        temp           tools`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It should be under `Android 4.0 (API 14)` *(since the doc always relates to the latest release)*, named `Documentation for Android SDK`.

*(at least it's there for me, I'm on linux though)*

[image]